# Ordenando select em ordem alfábetica com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando ordenar um `select` em ordem alfabética.

Tentei utilizar esta função que achei na internet

```
function ordenarSelect(){   
    f$(".slc_Reuniao").html($("option", $(".slc_Reuniao")).sort(function(a,b){
        return a.text == b.text  ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
    }));
};
```

Meu select inicial é:

```
 <select class="slc_Reuniao">
    <option value="SO" selected>--</option>             
 </select>
```

Apos rodo uma função que adiciona dinamicamente com `append` os nomes que voltaram da `query`. Preciso ordená-los.

Porem não está funcionando, ao contrario ele está gerando é novos `options`, estou utilizando `IndexedDB` como banco ele é baseado também em javascript, tentei procurar algo que no momento em que estou pesquisando os dados no banco eu ordena-se como no próprio `sql` porém não achei nada a respeito. 
Como devo fazer isto ?

> Em uma mesma página tenho 3 select cujo conteúdo é igual.

[image: Select gerando ao fazer o que me indicaram]

A forma de implementação é quando clico em um menu localizado em um sidemenu, dispara um evento que descrevo abaixo.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#cadReu", function(evt)
{
    var w_codigo_turma = sessionStorage.getItem('codigo');
    carregaSelectAluno(w_codigo_turma);
    ordenarSelect();
    activate_page("#cadastro_REUNIAO");
});
```

Apos ele chama a função `carregarSelectAluno()`, não irei adicionar pelo tamanho mais a função dele é apenas criar os `<option value""></option>` e adicionar no campo onde pego pelo comando `$wrapper = document.querySelector('.slc_Reuniao');` e coloco no select desta forma

```
   $( ".slc_Reuniao" ).each(function() {
      $(this).append(HTMLNovo);
    });
```

Apos isto chamo a função `ordenarSelect()` que é o local onde estou colocando as funções indicada pelas respostas da minha pergunta. Ambas dicas está dando mesmo problema. Não está organizando e está regerando. Um problema eu identifiquei que é quando volto ele adiciona novamente os nomes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode extrair os valores de cada `option` em um `array`, ordenar os valores e após, atualizar seu `select`. Ficaria assim o seu código:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    var n;
    var selects = $('select.slc_Reuniao');
  //console.log(selects);
    for(n = 0; n < selects.length; n++){
      var options = $('select.slc_Reuniao:eq('+n+') option');
       //console.log(opt);
      var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
        return {
            t: $(o).text(),
            v: o.value
        };
    }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
        return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
        console.log(i);
        o.value = arr[i].v;
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });
  

}
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="slc_Reuniao">
    <option value='PA'>Para</option>
    <option value='BA'>Bahia</option>
    <option value='MG'>Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value='ES'>Espirito Santo</option>
    <option value='PE'>Pernanbuco</option>
 </select>

 <select class="slc_Reuniao">
    <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>  
    <option value='RJ'>Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value='TO'>Tocantins</option>
    <option value="AC">Acre</option>  
    <option value='BA'>Bahia</option>
 </select>

 <select class="slc_Reuniao">
    <option value='BA'>Bahia</option>
    <option value="AC">Acre</option>  
    <option value='TO'>Tocantins</option>
    <option value='SC'>Santa Catarina</option>
    <option value='PA'>Para</option>
 </select>
```

### Edit

Para ordenar ao carregar a página, basta você colocar a função dentro do [$ (Document) .ready ()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) que ele chamará a função assim que sua página estiver pronta. Ficaria assim o código.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    var n;
    var selects = $('select.slc_Reuniao');
  //console.log(selects);
    for(n = 0; n < selects.length; n++){
      var options = $('select.slc_Reuniao:eq('+n+') option');
       //console.log(opt);
      var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
        return {
            t: $(o).text(),
            v: o.value
        };
    }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
        return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
        console.log(i);
        o.value = arr[i].v;
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });


}
 });
```

[Veja um exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/7v6dhrc2/)

Fonte: [Sorting Options - SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: Queria algo dinâmico, que não fosse necessário adicionar eventos a clicks,

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se lhe ajuda

Comment: Meu amigo, o metodo indicado para você está dando algo interessante, quando vou na pagina ele realiza apenas 4 mudanças, se eu saio e entro na pagina ele faz com todos os options do select porem ele bloqueia 3 select anteriores e o ultimo somente que fica funcionando. no log deu o seguinte resultado.` Montagem dos selects concluido com sucesso. main.js:29
0 
1 
2 
3 
Montagem dos selects concluido com sucesso. main.js:29
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10
11
12
13
14
15 `

Comment: Eu não entendi as edições de sua pergunta. Você possui vários `select's` e quer ordenar todos ao acessar à página, ou quer ordenar após alguma interação, ou ambas as opções?

Comment: Não, preciso ordenar todos os select ao acessar a pagina, na verdade eu monto ele desordenado e quero ordenar e mandar para pagina.

Comment: Pode alterar sua resposta para adequar ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues Editei a resposta novamente. Verifique se é isso que deseja.

Comment: Está acontecendo algo maluco, ele so pega o primeiro campo do select e como ele é `outro` ele não organiza. Estou chamando a função assim que acabo de colocar tudo no select. O que poderá está acontecendo ? Qual meu erro ?

Answer (score 3):

Tente o seguinte:

```
var options = $('select.whatever option');
var arr = options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
options.each(function(i, o) {
  o.value = arr[i].v;
  $(o).text(arr[i].t);
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/trELD/

Comment: Este método não funcionou.

Comment: Como vc está implementando?

Comment: editei minha pergunta veja la

Comment: Faça o seguinte, primeiro inclua as options desordenadas e depois rode a função que passei no meu exemplo

Answer (score 2):

Use está função para ordenar seu select

```
function ordenarSelect(id_componente)
{
  var selectToSort = jQuery('#' + id_componente);
  var optionActual = selectToSort.val();
  selectToSort.html(selectToSort.children('option').sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text === b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
  })).val(optionActual);
}




$(document).ready(function () {
  ordenarSelect('idMeuSelect');
});
```

Exemplo:

```js
function ordenarSelect(id_componente)
    {
      var selectToSort = jQuery('#' + id_componente);
      var optionActual = selectToSort.val();
      selectToSort.html(selectToSort.children('option').sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text === b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
      })).val(optionActual);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
      ordenarSelect('meuSelect');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select id="meuSelect">
    <option>Maria</option>
    <option>Pedro</option>
    <option>Zico</option>
    <option>Ana</option>
     <option>---</option>
    <option>Paulo</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Este método não funcionou.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo, observe que está funcionando. Qualquer duvida só pedir. Obrigado.